# Skip records in dataframe's map transformation

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a Spark dataframe on which I am doing certain operations as follows. I wanted to know how do I skip processing certain records going through all the operations

```
finalDf = df.map(mapFunc).reduceGroups(reduceFunc).map(mapFunc2).write().format().option().mode().save();
```

In the mapFunc, I want to write a logic that, if a certain condition is true, dont return anything and essential quit considering that record for further operations  `.reduceGroups(reduceFunc).map(mapFunc2).write().format().option().mode().save()`

I tried returning Optional.empty() from the map, but the code fails in reduceGroups with below error.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: head of empty list
    at scala.collection.immutable.Nil$.head(List.scala:420)
    at scala.collection.immutable.Nil$.head(List.scala:417)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.encoders.ExpressionEncoder$$anonfun$5.apply(ExpressionEncoder.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.encoders.ExpressionEncoder$$anonfun$5.apply(ExpressionEncoder.scala:120)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:381)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:234)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.map(List.scala:285)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.encoders.ExpressionEncoder$.tuple(ExpressionEncoder.scala:120)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.encoders.ExpressionEncoder$.tuple(ExpressionEncoder.scala:187)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.ReduceAggregator.bufferEncoder(ReduceAggregator.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Aggregator.toColumn(Aggregator.scala:100)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.KeyValueGroupedDataset.reduceGroups(KeyValueGroupedDataset.scala:436)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.KeyValueGroupedDataset.reduceGroups(KeyValueGroupedDataset.scala:448)
```

Schema for dataframe :

root
|-- id: string (nullable = true)
|-- mid: integer (nullable = true)
|-- responses: string (nullable = true)
|-- version: string (nullable = true)

In the mapFunc, i am processing responses string by doing substring and fetching value from it. In some cases, responses string can be empty so in such cases I dont want that entire record to be in finalDf;

```
Input

id mid responses version
A   1  "hello123" 1
B   1  "hello456" 2
A   2  "hello789" 5
A   1  "hello143" 4
B   3  "hello153" 6
C   3  ""         1

Output (Grouping by id, mid column)

id mid responses version
A   1  "143" 4
B   1  "456" 2
A   2  "789" 5
B   3  "153" 6
```

If responses  for (id,mid) combination of (C,3), was not empty, then  it would be in output. So i want to remove the the C,3 in the mapFunc.

Comment: what do you mean by don't return anything, can you add some sample data and expected output too ?

Comment: can you also add the mapFuc? Or you can just return the empty string as it is and use filter in next step

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here if you have a `map` function as below, then you can just return the same row and `filter` later with filter

```
val myFunc = (row: Row) => {
  val number = row.getString(2).replaceAll("\\D+","")
  (row.getString(0), row.getInt(1), number, row.getInt(3))
}

df.map(myFunc)
  .toDF(df.columns: _*)
  .filter(trim($"responses") =!= "" )
  .show(false)
```

Output:

```
+---+---+---------+-------+
|id |mid|responses|version|
+---+---+---------+-------+
|A  |1  |123      |1      |
|B  |1  |456      |2      |
|A  |2  |789      |5      |
|A  |1  |143      |4      |
|B  |3  |153      |6      |
+---+---+---------+-------+
```